# В webView не работает масштабирования (не приближается картинка)

Tags: java, android

Если обновить активити все  работает

Любые идеи  любые .

```
public class MainActivity2_3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2_3);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iczRI_b-Ik6ejmV2ZQ5jrtbzgnaeqZvH");

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
            }

            );



    }
    }
```

Comment: Может быть добавить

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true)

Comment: Не помогло , не могу поймать зависимость то работает то нет.Но если нет перезагрузка  webView.reload();  помогает.